# Solr - Combine Block Join Query and parent query with "OR"

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working with many collections in Solr 6.3 and they can be rather generic. In some of them, I might need to do a single query on both children and parent fields, using an "OR" operator. For illustration, suppose I have the following documents indexed in Solr:

```
{id: doc1,
 type: parent,
 specs: spec1,
 NESTED_DOC_KEY:[
                 {id:child1, childspecs:spec1, type:child},
                 {id:child2, childspecs:spec2, type:child},
                ]},
 {id: doc2,
 type: parent,
 specs: spec2,
 NESTED_DOC_KEY:[
                 {id:child3, childspecs:spec3, type:child},
                ]},
 {id: doc3,
 type: parent,
 specs: spec3,
 NESTED_DOC_KEY:[
                 {id:child4, childspecs:spec4, type:child},
                ]},
 }
```

I need to find, for instance, all documents with specs:spec3 OR documents with one child with childspecs:spec1. So I expect to find doc1 and doc3. I tried the following query syntax, but it returns all three documents and child1:

```
specs:spec3 OR {!parent which="type:parent"} childspecs:spec1
```

Each query works separately, so I could join the results outside Solr, but I would like to know if there is a way to do this as a single query in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, it is the "space" between the "{!parent which="type:parent"}" and "childspecs:spec1". It was probably interpreting as two different queries, and that is why I was getting all the parent documents and the child1.